# Security options for Standalone Solr without zookeeper

Tags: solr, sitecore, apache-zookeeper

I am using Solr 6.2.1.2 as standalone search with my Sitecore 8, what options I have to secure my search without using **Zookepper**. Not much documentation available specially for Standalone Solr security.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "secure my search"? Zookepper is rather about reliability, not security?

Comment: I see lots of documents for Solr security but all are based on using Zookeeper configuration files, I do not have Zookeeper installed. I want configure specific servers to /put and specific server can /select on Solr.

Answer (score 1):

Even though, Solr is nowadays delivered with its own Jetty, it is still just a web application for a container application. Thus, it relies completely on its surroundings for things like authentication or authorization. The shiny new Solrcloud mode works with Zookeper, that's why so many solutions exist that use Zookeepers security features. It's just already there.

When you run Solr as stand-alone server without the cloud features, you will have to configure the underlying Jetty server accordingly or use some other software for security. I would recommend using nginx here.

1. Block external traffic to the Solr port via iptables
2. Configure nginx to forward a certain URL to your Solr
3. Configure nginx to allow certain sub-URLs only for certain servers

Comment: Thanks @seven.windisch, do you have any documentation or tutorial for the same?

Comment: Unfortunately not. That's just what we are doing at my company when it comes to securing Solr servers.

Answer (score 1):

[Nirav Desai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6220530/nirav-desai) in case that you want just to make a few tests on Solr  with authentication turned on, without depending on Zookeeper, then you have to wait for the next stable release of Solr 6.5 or 7.0 (current version of Solr is 6.4.1).

In the next release of Solr supports a standalone version of BasicAuthPlugin.

Once you have the latest version of Solr, you just need to create a security.json file in ${solr.home}/server/solr directory and restart the Solr server.

Afterwards call http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/authentication and you should see that the authentication was enabled.

Development details on the standalone support for BasicAuthPlugin can be found here:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-9481

Documentation details for the BasicAuthPlugin can be found here:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Basic+Authentication+Plugin

Comment: Thank you @marius_neo, looking forward to the next release.